# Effect of disrespecting parents

Tags: salat, parents, forgiveness

I am now aware that disrespecting my parents is a major sin in Islam and if you do it you will not enter paradise and all your duas and prayers will not be accepted.

However, when I was younger, I did not know that this sin had these major consequences, so I sometimes would disrespect my parents or talk back to them in a rude way. Does that mean that all of my previous prayers and duas are not accepted?

Sometimes I do things that might slightly annoy them, or I might shout a bit when I am very angry when they are very unfair to me, but my parents are not mad at me, and I did it out of control and much awareness, and later everyone forgets about it and it is no big deal. Do I still have to ask for and pray for forgiveness from Allah for this disrespect?

I am confused about how this works. Does it mean that every time I might disrespect, my prayer and dua stops being accepted?

Answer (score 1):

1. When a person commits sins it doesn't mean his dua's can't be answered, dua is still a form of worship and a realization of Tawheed, Shaytaan was disobedient and became a kafir and his dua was still answered, since Allah is ar-Raheem. Thought what needs to be mentioned is that sins block your dua's from being accepted, but in the general sense, a pious believer will have his dua more likely to be answered than a sinner.
2. Allah says you shouldn't even say "oof" to your parents, so whenever you do that or something worse than it you should definitely repent and try not to return to it, the fact that you acknowledge how severe this is, is a good sign
3. Having good manners, especially with your parents/family, is from the best of the best of deeds in islam, so try your best to change your bad habit, you can be mad or frustrated but that doesn't have to (and shouldn't) turn into you physically acting upon it, keep it in yourself, forgive and overlook, because forgiving is from the characteristics of the people of paradise as mentioned in Surah Ali-Imran

Comment: @MusaAdeel Most likely not authentic since I have never heard this hadith stated by anyone